# Why are my anchor links pushing content behind my header?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have a layout where the header section uses absolute positioning and when I click on an anchor
link in my content, the link takes me to the right place but it pushes my content up behind the header.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Here is the URL:

http://digitaldemo.net/joy/krippen-a-b-c/

Many thanks!

Cynthia

Comment: are you using any javascript when clicking on the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 'overflow: hidden' on your #container style and your #content style. Try commenting those two declarations out and see if that helps.

Comment: That solved that problem :) Unfortunately the overflow:hidden on the #content div was what was enabling my equal column heights so now I hvae to find an alternative for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check **z-index** css property of the anchor tag as well as header tag.

Comment: Neither have z-index properties. I believe they inherit the z-index of the container (#body) div.